# IE9 conditional comments -- why don't they work

Tags: internet-explorer, xhtml

I found so many questions to this topic, but none of the answers helped, so I ask again.

I have a web site (php) with this head section:

```
<?php header( 'Content-type: application/xhtml+xml' ); ?>
<?php header( 'X-UA-Compatible: IE=9' ); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color: #000000;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

the conditional comment does just not work, not matter what i try, what's wrong? I need the xhtml headers for xpath, so I cannot drop them.

Greetings...

**EDIT:**

It seems to be the header of line 1 that disables their functionality, but without it xpath does not work...

Comment: does not work how? your bg color doesn't change?

Comment: jess... I want to add an additional javascript, so that is the the tryout, but :: fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional comments are not compatible with XML parsing rules, so IE just treats them as normal comments in pages served as `application/xhtml+xml`.

There's nothing you can do about this. Just don't use them.